# how to persist data in database after uninstalling application?

Tags: javascript, android, html, sqlite, cordova

I want to implement Offline Data Storage functionality in my application. The scenario will be like the data will be stored even if the user clears data from App manager or even when the user uninstalls the application.

I am using the following code where I am creating a database and a table in it.

```js
 
var db = window.openDatabase("../../../../storage/emulated/0/test.db", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
  
  
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Alice', 101]);
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Betty', 202]);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
  }, function() {
    console.log('Populated database OK');
  });
```

After this, a database file is created in the internal storage of mobile device with the name: <>test.db

After uninstalling the application/clearing the application data, the table in the database is deleted.
Can someone please help me with persisting the data after uninstalling the application.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that it is not possible? (well, besides some cloud storage)

Comment: Cloud storage is the only way here !

Comment: Mine is offline scenario so cloud storage won't work and for security reason if user uninstall the app.Like whatsapp keeps database at some location.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to persist even after uninstallation, you should save your DB file in location as given by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`. **Be reminded that all files you put into that directory is world-readable.**

There are also other things that you need to consider when using external directory such as its availability. More here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SQLite you can go for NoSQL Database and store your app data in files. By uninstalling the app, the app data will be persistent as you'll  have the liberty to store the data in external storage of the device

I would recommend please go through

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.1.0/develop/training/build-first-android-app/index.html

Its a very good library for android NoSQL DB, if you cant use SQLite.

Comment: using `Internal storage`, all app data will be erased when you uninstall your app.

Comment: I am concernd that if my database is inside my application it will be erased but i want to store database at different location so even after uninstalling app,data must persist(like Whatsapp).

Comment: No, in this case your database will not be inside your app. You can define its location eg. Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()